# RxAndroid message queue timeout

Tags: android, timeout, queue, rx-java, rx-android

I have messages incoming from web socket.
They include state changes to some objects
Let's name these states A, B, C

messages:
A
A
B
C
C
A

I am interested only in the last state (A) and ONLY after some time 
of no activity on ws related to this type of messages. So, to somehow 
queue them up, and after some inactivity(1000ms) act on that
last (A) message (any message before that last one is of no interest).
How would I implement it using RxAndroid ?
(I already have wired up Retrolambda and all related to Rx, also have
a couple of methods working some async stuff)

Comment: Maybe try `debounce()` on the observable of Message A? http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html

Comment: Tnx for the operator, but a bit of code would help more

Comment: Sorry I was in a rush and wanted to help out with at least a quick reference to something that might help you. Apologies if it wasn't helpful.

Comment: No need to apologize, it was helpful to some extent. I'm familiar with RX only to some extent, so, code talks :)

Answer (score 1):

i guess in your case better to use `.sample()` instead of `.debounce()`

```
Observable<Message> debouncedStream = messageObservable
    .samlpe(1 , TimeUnit.Seconds);
```

See the difference [sample](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/images/sample.png) and [debounce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/images/debounce.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter messages based on their type and then debounce:

```
 Observable<Message> debouncedStream = messageObservable
.filter(message -> message.getType().equals("A"))
.debounce(1 , TimeUnit.Seconds);
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to filter them, i will pre-filter them before going into this rx stuff. I just want to use last one after no new message arrives.